# $f,f'$ bounded but $f''$ unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

True or false:

> Let $f:(0,1)\to \Bbb R$ be a twice differentiable function, then, if $f$ and $f'$ bounded, then $f''$ bounded.

I tried integrating $x\sin (1/x)$, but $F(x)=\int x\sin (1/x) dx$ seems to be unbounded.

Does it have to do something with $f'$ bounded then $f$ uniformly continuous?

Comment: You said that codomain of $f$ is $R$, so you mean for any real number $y$ there exists $x$ in domain of $f$ such that $y=f(x)$ ? If so, how can $f$ be bounded ?

Comment: Is $f$ a twice differentiable function in $[0,1]$ (closed)?

Comment: @RobertZ, sorry! fixing that. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $x^{3/2}$? First derivative is $\frac{3}{2} x^{1/2}$, second is $ \frac{3}{4} x^{-1/2} $.